# How to manually obtain the minus log-likelihood in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I'm implementing a VAE and I want to obtain the negativev log-likelihood manually (not using an existing function). The given equation is [equation1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErdmM.png), and I have also found it can as well be expressed as [equation2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMhdE.png). I have been stuck on this for a couple of days now, and don't know where my code is wrong.

```
def loss_loglik(y_mean, y_logvar, x):
    out_1 = (x.size()[2]*x.size()[3] / 2) * np.log(2 * np.pi)
    out_2 = (x.size()[2]*x.size()[3] / 2) * torch.log(y_logvar.exp())
    x_diff = x - y_mean
    out_3 = torch.sum(x_diff.pow(2)) / (2 * y_logvar.exp())
    loss = out_1 + out_2 + out_3
```

The shape of the three arguments is (batch_size, 1, 28, 28).

Comment: How do you know your code is wrong?

Comment: Because I test with some input values and have the answer for that specific case, which is different from the one I obtain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like eq. 2 is wrong.

It should have been something like. I did not derive it, just trying to match with the input... so, please verify.

[image]

I modified your function below.

```
def loss_loglik(y_mean, y_logvar, x):
    m, n  = x.size()[2], x.size()[3]
    b = x.size()[0]
    
    y_mean = y_mean.reshape(B, -1)
    y_logvar = y_loagvar.reshape(B, -1)


    out_1 = (m*n / 2) * np.log(2 * np.pi)
    
    out_2 = (1 / 2) * y_logvar.sum(dim=1)
    
    x_diff = x - y_mean
    # note sigma is inside the sum
    out_3 = torch.sum(x_diff.pow(2) / (2 * y_logvar.exp()), dim=1)
    
    loss = out_1 + out_2 + out_3
    
    return -loss      
    # shape of loss will be (batchsize,)
```

Comment: Although this is almost the same implementation I had, the error was that I shouldn't take the first element into account (for my specific case).

Comment: I just updated to take care of the batch dimension too. Hope it helps

Comment: Btw, what do you mean  with "I did not derive it..."? Shall we derive it? Sorry if the question seems too obvious, for my understanding I just need to implement it in order to get the log likelihood.

Comment: I meant that your Eq 2 which is derived by substituting distribution parameters in Eq 1 seemed wrong, and eventually, your implementation was wrong. See there is no sum over sigma_i in the second term or sigma_i is not in the summation in the third term in your implementation. I did not fully derive the result that I have mentioned in my answer and wrote it by intuition and observing your expression for Eq. 2. Hence my comment that you might have to "mathematically derive" it to make sure it is correct.